# homebrew install hangs on mac

Tags: macos, rvm, homebrew

I can't figure this one out when I try to install rvm it just hangs (on mac 10.8.5):

```
Installing required packages: libksba....
```

Doing a cntrl+c i can see in the log:

```
current path: /Users/markewest/.rvm/src/rvm
command(2): requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libksba
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/libksba
==> Installing dependencies for libksba: libgpg-error
==> Installing libksba dependency: libgpg-error
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.12.tar.bz2
```

I have tried manually installing "libgpg-error" and it doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Edit:  Tried the below suggestion but it gets stuck. Nothing ever download, it shows below (after letting it sit for 1 hour):

```
==> Installing dependencies for libksba: libgpg-error
==> Installing libksba dependency: libgpg-error
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.12.tar.bz2
```

Comment: try manually: `brew install libksba`

Comment: Thanks mpapis.  Edited my post with what happens...still stuck

Comment: So it seems like it is just not downloading libgpg-error via the homebrew formula.  I paste it in the browser and it wont download either.  If I manually install it from a mirror 'brew doctor' gives me errors about unbrewed dylibs and .la files.  Still stuck on this one.

Comment: is your brew up to date? if this still happens open a ticket for homebrew with the details (do not mention rvm to avoid blame game - you can reproduce it without rvm).

Answer (score 2):

Got this to work by downloading the files from a mirror and dropping them into the Homebrew Cache.  More here: [Homebrew Tips N' Tricks](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Tips-N%27-Tricks#pre-downloading-a-file-for-a-formula)

After that I was able to run brew install on both files libksba, libgpg-error and they installed fine.

Comment: This link is broken, but this is the right approach. When this happens to me I remove `/Users/whitlock/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/*.incomplete`. This usually clears the problem right up.